# Add space from a NTFS partition to Ubuntu

Tags: windows, 14.04, windows-8, ntfs, ext4

So, i installed Ubuntu alongside my Windows 8 on a 15 GB partition i took from another drive . Ubuntu splitted it into 2 partitions of 7,96 GB and 7,04 GB and i realized that it's kind of small so i want to add more space. I was thinking about trying to take space again and allocating it to those 2 partitions, but i'm afraid something will go wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While it may be rare, but something can go wrong, so I strongly advise you to back up your most important data.

As far as resizing partitions, this is very easily done by booting into a gparted CD.

Just boot to the gparted disk select that partition you want to resize and use the gui to stretch it (or shrink it) to the preferred size.

Comment: So i can use gparted to take take space from the NTFS partition and allocate it to the ext4 one aswell? Or should i do that from windows disk management first and then resize it with gparted?

Comment: For a detailed description you can look at this page: http://howtoubuntu.org/how-to-resize-partitions-with-the-ubuntu-or-gparted-live-cd

Comment: While gparted usually will work with Windows, often better to use Windows to shrink the Windows NTFS system partition. And either way immediately reboot into Windows so it can run chkdsk and make repairs for its new size. Do not create partitions with Windows.

Comment: @d33psc4n since it you've already mentioned you have a Ubuntu alongside Windows, it you're most likely booting grub.  That part probably doesn't matter.  But the bottom line, since if you'll be booting to the gparted disk, that's a linux boot process, so you'll inadvertently be booting to linu while you're performing the operation.  So yes you can use gparted to manage all your partition sizes.